# ext-authoryear style not found and DeclareInnerCiteDelims not working

Tags: biblatex

I am very new to LaTeX and this whole environment is pretty confusing to me so far, so please bear with me if I did sth stupid!

Hope that the MWE below is a good starting point:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,english]{report}
% package loading
% encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % new

% page and text layout setup
\usepackage[a4paper,top=20mm,bottom=10mm,left=20mm,right=50mm]{geometry}

% language and spelling check
\usepackage{babel}

% miscellaneous document formatting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% document structuring
% table of content formatting
\usepackage{tocloft}
% appendix
\usepackage{appendix}

% tables and lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}

% graphics and images display
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% table and list formatting and referencing
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

% math symbols and formula display
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% including hyperlinks in the ToC for easier navigation
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}

% bibliography management and back-end
% setting referencing + citation styles
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, autocite=footnote, maxnames=1, sorting=nyt, sortcites=true, giveninits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

% customize bibliography formatting
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\slash\space}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{ %eliminates the 'in' in the bibliography
\ifentrytype{article}{}{%
\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% reference your '.bib' file that stores all your sources
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% advanced document formatting
% line spacing, paragraph indention and paragraph spacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\onehalfspacing % \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\pagestyle{plain}

% redefining title layouts
\titleformat{\chapter} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{8pt}{} 
\titleformat{\section} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{8pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection.}{8pt}{}

% title spacing for chapters and lower-level sections
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

% set font
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% define any style difference to main document before begin document
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}

% main document creation
\begin{document}
   
\input{titlepage}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\input{chapters/Abstract}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Attachments}
\chapter*{Table of attachments}
\input{chapters/Table_of_attachments}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\chapter*{List of abbreviations}
\input{chapters/List_of_abbreviations}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Symbols}
\chapter*{List of symbols}
\input{chapters/List_of_symbols}

% Introduction title
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

% Chapter One Title
\chapter{Literature review}
\input{chapters/Chapter01}

% Chapter Two Title
\chapter{Empirical analysis}
\input{chapters/Chapter02}

% Chapter Three Title
\chapter{Discussion of results}
\input{chapters/Chapter03}

% Conclusion Title
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\appendix
\input{chapters/Appendix}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\input{chapters/Acknowledgements}
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Declaration of Academic Integrity}
\chapter*{Declaration of academic integrity}
\input{chapters/Statement_integrity}

\end{document}
```

Currently, I am seeing three errors.

1. /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty,
   line 13046 **Package biblatex Error: Style 'ext-authoryear' not
   found.** l.13046 \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}. The
   bibliography style 'ext-authoryear' could not be found.
2. /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex,
   line 13047 **Package biblatex Error: Style 'ext-authoryear' not
   found.** See the biblatex package documentation for explanation
   l.13047 \RequireCitationStyle{\blx@cbxfile}. The citation style
   'ext-authoryear.sty' could not be found.
3. l.61 **\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}** The
   control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
   was never \def'ed.

Note that, whenever I change the style back to the base biblatex `author year` style, the citations and footnotes work just fine, expect the `DeclareInnerCiteDelime` command doesn't seem to do anything, and I am still missing the parentheses around the `year` in my footnotes.

Would highly appreciate any pointers and/or comments! Thanks

Comment: You are running TeX Live 2017 which does not provide the `biblatex-ext` files. The first public release of this package was 2018-03-08

Comment: Oh man, ... That caused me hours of headache trying to debug and rewriting the whole preamble numerous times in the attempt to catch the error that was causing all this. Thanks! Highly appreciated!

I am using my school's online LaTeX editor shareLaTeX. Might need to work on my offline based Tex software program then.

Comment: There was an option hidden deep inside the project settings. Two Tex Live versions available. ```Tex Live 2017.1``` and ```Tex Live 2020.1```. Changed the setting and worked like a charm! 

Once I knew where to look, it was easy! Your help was much appreciated Ivan!

Comment: @Ivan Do you want to type up a quick answer here? Or do we close this as too localised?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but since you are using `biblatex-ext` you can remove your redefinition of `\renewbibmacro{in:}` and use the option `articlein=false,` instead. `\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\slash\space}` can be replaced with `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space}` and you may want to do something for `finalnamedelim` otherwise things might end up looking weird (maybe `\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}`)

Comment: @moewe You can close it.

Comment: Thanks for these kind suggestions Moewe! I'll write up a quick answer myself. Thanks

Comment: Note, that apparently as a new user here, I can only accept and thus close this question in 2 days.

@moewe: Would you be so kind and shortly elaborate on what exactly the ```\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}```will do? I did already implement the other changes you proposed, but I don't quite fully understand the aforementioned proposal. Thx

Comment: I guess an example is worth a thousand words: https://gist.github.com/moewew/8823bc4d32aee071a1cd83e7dcbbbdf8. Compare the output with `\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}` commented out and uncommented.

Comment: Thank you! Highly apprciated :) Now it's crytsal clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here was already hidden in the helpful error messages, but only thanks to Ivan, I finally realized where I had to look.

Essentially the `ext-biblatex` styles are **only supported by TeX Live versions from `2018-03-08` onwards** which was the public release date of the `biblatex-ext` package. As I was using TeX Live 2017 in my online LaTeX editor shareLaTeX, the defined `ext` style could not be found. Quickly changing the setting to use a later TeX Live version (2020.1 in my case), everything worked as expected!